# How to dynamically change TChart's Panel's color in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, charts

While in IDE Panel's parameters are shown in Chart->Panel->Parameters (e.g. color). I can't use this method in code though: `Chart.Panel.Color:=RGB(0,0,0);//doesn't work` Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: I know, but usually properties are organized using the same logic as in IDE.

Comment: Yes, I realized that inconsistency. Anyway, it was enough to set that color for instance to `clLime` and you'd notice the `Color` property change in Object Inspector.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `Color` property, e.g., `Chart1.Color := clYellow`.